# Visual Studio 2010 SP1 and Team Foundation Server 2010 compatibility

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is Visual Studio 2010 SP1 compatible with Team Foundation Server 2010, or should I update also TFS 2010 to SP1 before upgrading VS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Brian Harry's [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/03/09/installing-all-the-new-stuff.aspx), it's got loads of really useful information about the SP1 release. Short answer is yes you can use VS 2010 SP1 with TFS 2010 (no SP) unless they are both on the same machine. In that scenario you must apply both SP's

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be working here OK. And previous cases (eg. VS2008 SP1 and TFS 2008 RTM) have worked.

I would assume *yes* unless you find something specific to the contrary.

EDIT: (As also noted in another answer): Brian Harry covers this in his ["what to install where"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/03/09/installing-all-the-new-stuff.aspx) post. Under **FAQ**:

> **Can an RTM VS work with an SP1 TFS or can an SP1 VS work with an RTM TFS?**  Yes to both.  There is no requirement that the client and server be at the same servicing level.